# Enable write_http in collectd

Tags: collectd

I am trying to build collectd from source and want to explore write_http plugin. However when configure is run, it shows:

```
write_graphite  . . . yes  
write_http  . . . . . no  
write_kafka . . . . . no
```

How to enable it? Is there some specific dependency needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enable the write_http plugin,install the libcurl-devel dependency

```
apt-get install -y libcurl-devel
```